# How do I know the discount rate?

Tags: commerce

Hi I wont to know about how can I use discount rate ?

```
$report_query = db_select('commerce_order','co');
$report_query->fields('co');
$report_query->orderBy('co.created','ASC');
$report_res = $report_query->execute();
while ($re = $report_res->fetchObject()) {
    $o_id = $re->order_id;
    $o_load = commerce_order_load($o_id);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($o_load);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1] => Array(
[name] => tax|vat_cst
[price] => Array(
        [amount] => 27556
        [currency_code] => INR
        [data] => Array(
                [tax_rate] => Array(                    
                        [name] => vat_cst
                        [display_title] => VAT/CST
                        [description] => VAT
                        [rate] => 0.125 // here display tax rate
                        [type] => vat
                        [rules_component] => commerce_tax_rate_vat_cst
                        [default_rules_component] => 1
                        [price_component] => tax|vat_cst
                        [calculation_callback] => commerce_tax_rate_calculate
                        [module] => commerce_tax_ui
                        [title] => VAT/CST
                        [admin_list] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
[included] => 1
) 

[2] => Array(
   [name] => discount-20% Off
   [price] => Array(
        [amount] => -49600
        [currency_code] => INR
        [data] => Array(                                           
          [discount_name] => discount_full_discount_20_
          [discount_component_title] => 20% Off
        )
   )
   [included] => 1
)
```

In vat_cst the rate is 0.125 but,how can I know which rate is used on total order?

Answer (score 0):

The discount *rate* isn't always available as a percentage (like, for instance, taxes are) because discounts can be whole numbers as well. Regardless, you can ultimately get information about how a price is calculated by looking at the `commerce_order_total` field on an `order` or the `commerce_total` field on a `line_item`.

Here's an example:

[image: Debugging screen shot for a commerce order.]

In this screen shot, we'll take a look at 4 items. For the comments assume `$price = $order->commerce_order_total[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]`.

1. `$price['data']['components'][0]['price']['amount']` is the original amount. You know this because `$price['data']['components'][0]['price']['amount']` is `"base_price"`.
2. A discount price component will a name of `"discount|DISCOUNT_ID"` where `DISCOUNT_ID` is the machine name of the discount that is being referenced.
3. `$price['data']['components'][1]['price']['amount']` in this instance is the discount that is applied.
4. `$price['amount']` is the combination of all of the components under `$price['data']['components']`.

There is a `data` array under the price information on the discount. It contains the label and the machine name of the discount, but it doesn't have any other information. Custom discounts might put more information on there, but you can't necessarily depend on anything else being there.